# Using "have ran" or "have run"

Tags: tenses, simple-past-as-past-participle

I was editing a piece recently and saw this structure

"Once you have ran the process, you ..."

I have always used "have run", but wasn't sure if "have ran" is acceptable in modern English.

If it helps, the writer is British (I am American), so not sure if this is a place where cultural differences come into play.

Comment: I hear this mistake from time to time in the U.S.

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you?

Comment: Not really addressed in the dictionary. I see "have to run", but not have run or have ran. I lean towards the former as correct, but asked here to get other thoughts.

Comment: What's the mistake? Have ran or have run?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It appears to be just a grammatical error as suggested by the following [source](https://languageandgrammar.com/2008/06/18/have-you-run-into-this-grammar-error/)
and as shown also in  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20ran&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20ran%3B%2Cc0)

> - ***The past participle is run.*** I have run into resistance every time I’ve tried to solve the problem. She has run from her responsibilities.
> - Regarding the problem that arises when forming the past participle, ***some people mistakenly use the past tense ran instead of the correct past participle run,***  as in *I have ran into resistance every time I’ve tried to resolve this problem* or *She has ran from her responsibilities.*
> - (I’ve also heard some people make the same mistake when forming a sentence in the past perfect tense, as in I had ran them down before they left the office, which should be I had run them down…) Do yourself a favor: Run as far from these constructions as possible—and don’t look back.

(languageandgrammar.com)

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/ran) "ran" is also:

> - (nonstandard, dialectal) past participle of run

Comment: @Clare - Where do you draw the line, then?  And do you have some documentation for "ran" as an acceptable past participle of "run"?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would this also have true for "would have run" ?